# How to call a method on a custom view in an Espresso test?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-testing, android-espresso

I have a custom view on which I need to call a specific method to open an activity. What is the right way to do this in an Espresso test?
Do I just need to inflate this view or do I need to write a custom `ViewAction`?

Comment: i dont' understand the problem, you need to call the method on a custom view that is inside an activity, or you just need to start the activity from scratch?

Comment: I need to call a method on the custom view

Comment: For clarification, do you want a unit test of the Activity, or is this for integration test?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

you can create a custom ViewAction like this

```
public class MyCustomViewAction implements ViewAction{

    @Override
    public Matcher<View> getConstraints(){
        return isAssignableFrom(YourCustomView.class);
    }


    @Override
    public String getDescription(){
        return "whatever";
    }

    @Override
    public void perform(UiController uiController, View view){
        YourCustomView yourCustomView = (YourCustomView) view;
        yourCustomView.yourCustomMethod();
        // tadaaa
    }

}
```

and use it as you normally would, like

```
onView(withId(whatever)).perform(new MyCustomViewAction());
```

Comment: How to get back the result and pass it to assertion methods?

Comment: @everlasto, you're better posting your question as a separate StackOverflow thread. The original question has been answered in this thread.

Answer (score 1):

In order to use the result of a custom method in assertions, I came up with the following modification of lellomans answer:

```
public class MyCustomViewAction implements ViewAction{
    MyReturnObject returnValue = null;

    @Override
    public Matcher<View> getConstraints(){
        return isAssignableFrom(YourCustomView.class);
    }


    @Override
    public String getDescription(){
        return "whatever";
    }

    @Override
    public void perform(UiController uiController, View view){
        YourCustomView yourCustomView = (YourCustomView) view;
        // store the returnValue   
        returnValue = yourCustomView.yourCustomMethod();
    }   
}
```

and instead of creating a new MyCustomViewAction(), I created a myAction object for later reuse.

```
MyCustomViewAction myAction = new MyCustomViewAction();
onView(withId(whatever)).perform(myAction);
MyReturnObject returnValueForSpecialAssertions = myAction.returnValue;
// assert something with returnValueForSpecialAssertions
```

Comment: This, in my mind, goes against how Espresso tests are intended to be written. Firstly. if calling the custom method affects the UI, then assertions should be made on the state of the UI after the call. Secondly, if it is still important to assert on the result passed out of the custom method, then most likely the custom method should be tested in isolation outside of a UI test. (On the second point: there's most likely some business logic in the view which can be pulled out of the view to make testing easier.)